# VisualForce Controller in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
return ApexPages.getMessages().size() -1;
```

Iam Using aboveLine in Visualforce Page controller. Please explain About this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApexPages.getMessages() returns a list of messages associated with the current context.
If we specify ApexPages.getMessages().size()-1 it will return the latest entry or the last entry in the list of messages.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the **count** (size) of the messages list and reduced by 1.

(i.e) `ApexPages.getMessages()` has **2** messages, then

`ApexPages.getMessages().size()` will return **2** and

this one -  `ApexPages.getMessages().size() -1;` will return **1**.